# Error on creating FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, sql, reference, foreign-keys, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `servergraph_server` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    `ip` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
    `port` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `servergraph_data` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `serverid` INT NOT NULL, 
    `time` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    `fps` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `replay` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `dropped_packets` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `online` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `clients0` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `clients1` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `clients2` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `clients3` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (`serverid`) REFERENCES `servergraph_server` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

This are the tables I'd like to create.

But I am always getting an error on the FOREIGN KEY line.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIG' at line 1
```

I am using this version of MySQL: 5.5.35-0+wheezy1

What is wrong?

Thanks, floube

**SOLUTION:**

```
ALTER TABLE `servergraph_data` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_server` FOREIGN KEY (`serverid`) REFERENCES `servergraph_server` (`id`)
```

instead of the FOREIGN KEY line in CREATE TABLE servergraph_data

Comment: Are you executing this as a script?

Comment: No, I execute them from inside a plugin, but it supports MySQL

Comment: Your DDL works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8702e Something else is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Place semi colons after the create table statements:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `servergraph_server` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    `ip` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
    `port` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `servergraph_data` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `serverid` INT NOT NULL, 
    `time` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    `fps` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `replay` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `dropped_packets` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `online` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `clients0` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `clients1` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `clients2` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `clients3` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (`serverid`) REFERENCES `servergraph_server` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```